# Auto testing a Play for Scala application

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.5

Should I test it using JUnit (as proposed in Play's website) or should I test the GET and POST responses in the javascript, using a tool like Selenium (by the way, my front-end is AngularJS). What are the pros/cons?

Comment: Are you asking if it worth to have unit tests for your models and controllers? Are you familiar with the [test pyramid concept](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestPyramid.html)?

Comment: what is the best way to test a Play application?

Comment: You can just follow the documentation, which is pretty clear and direct about [how to test your application](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaTestingYourApplication).

Comment: Thanks, I was just wondering if that's the best way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personnaly, I use scala-test for those test, you can provide a custom database, do some FakeRequest,  and see if the results are correct.

There is a lot of documentation on this subject on the Play framework website :

- [Testing your application with ScalaTest](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaTestingWithScalaTest)
- [Writing Functionnal test with ScalaTest](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaFunctionalTestingWithScalaTest)

Good luck ;)